# MongoDB won't start as service

Tags: mongodb, cpanel, centos6

I recently installed mongodb on a Centos Dedicated Server. When i try to start mongodb as a service it is give me the following error.

Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]

When i just execute mongod this is what i receive.

```
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2566 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=sv.redswitches.com
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-10-27T03:54:46.184+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-10-27T03:54:46.195+0100 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-10-27T03:54:46.196+0100 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-10-27T03:54:46.233+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2014-10-27T03:54:46.233+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] now exiting
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.234+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.244+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.244+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-10-27T03:54:46.244+0100 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.244+0100 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-10-27T03:54:46.254+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-10-27T03:54:46.254+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

I have already tried to re-install it twice still nothing. I also have cPanel installed on this server.

Comment: Removing and installing the latest build solved the problem. Remove the current installation and use yum install -y mongodb-org  to install the latest build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears it is already running:

> ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
>   2014-10-27T03:54:46.233+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use

Another process is already using that port which is most likely another Mongo instance. Try running

```
mongo
```

from your command line prompt to see if you can connect using the MongoDB shell utility. Alternatively try

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 27017
```

and see which process is using port 27017. On my system it's mongo:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25480/mongod
```

Comment: Actually i just re-installed it again and installed the latest build yum install -y mongodb-org . Seems to have solved the problem.